# Using Python to specific values from multiple PDFs and converting it to 1 excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pdf, scrape

I am working with PDF documents containing lab results. The PDFs are identical except for the customer name, along with the respective sample value. Can Python be used to extract the specific values from the given location on the page and export to 1 excel document ? This would ideally be done in a batch format.

Comment: Convert the PDF to Text and grab the values as I asume is a template PDF. here is a link how to convert to text a PDF using python https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

Comment: As to create a Excel file use another python library http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/